# How to avoid overloaded assignment operator turning rvalue to lvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11

To my knowledge, returning `*this` is the norm of writing overloaded `operator=`. But this may promote a rvalue to a lvalue!

```
struct Foo {
  Foo& operator=(const Foo &t) { return *this; }
};

int main() {
  const Foo &ref = Foo();
  //Foo &ref1 = Foo();  // This line won't compile.
  //But the following line compiles. Isn't it dangerous?
  //Also please note that if = is not overloaded, the synthesized operator= will NOT let it compile.
  Foo &ref2 = (Foo() = Foo());

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean: a **non-const** lvalue?

Comment: I think g++ is actually wrong to cause an error when `Foo`'s definition is empty.  Submitted http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54319

Comment: C++ also allows you to write `system("format C: /y")` which is even more dangerous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right.  The short answer is that this is legal, but is dangerous for the reasons you point out.

Another (similar) example was added to C++11, as part of the standard no less, with the rvalue stream output, which returns an lvalue reference.

```
template <class charT, class traits, class T>
basic_ostream<charT, traits>&
operator<<(basic_ostream<charT, traits>&& os, const T& x);
```

So `std::ostream& s = std::ofstream("foo.txt") << "Oh boy";` is legal, but creates a dangling reference.

I believe that C++11 compilers will allow member functions to be restricted to the case when the object is an lvalue, which should allow you to prevent the problem at all.  The below will only allow the assignment when `*this` is an lvalue, so it prevents you from converting by accident.

```
struct Foo {
  Foo& operator=(const Foo &t) & { return *this; }
};
```

Comment: @updogliu What compiler are you using?  I believe g++ doesn't yet support ref-qualifiers on member functions.

Comment: "_For objects with an overloaded assignment operator,_" even with the compiler generated one!

Comment: @curiousguy:  You're right.  When I tested without the user-defined, I was using g++ 4.7 in C++11 mode, and that generates an error (see http://ideone.com/MJIjA ).  I'll edit it.

Comment: @DaveS Which compiler supports the `struct Foo` in this answer? g++ 4.6.3 in C++0x cannot compile it.

Answer (score 1):

As the first answer points out, what you're doing is legal but will result in a dangling reference. You can achieve much the same result without overloading the assignment operator:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
  Foo(int arg) : val(arg) { std::cout << "ctor " << val << "\n"; }
  ~Foo() { std::cout << "dtor " << val << "\n"; }
  int val;
};

int main() {
  Foo &ref = (Foo(1) = Foo(2));
  std::cout << "undefined behavior: " << ref.val << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Produces the following output:

> ctor 1
>   ctor 2
>   dtor 2
>   dtor 2
>   undefined behavior: 2

As you can see, the temporary for `Foo(1)` is constructed followed by the temporary for `Foo(2)`. However both objects are destroyed before we can do anything with the reference, so the subsequent line results in undefined behavior.